# How to select a option from list using Javascript, so that it also trigger an event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to automate something here. The website on which I run the Javascript,

When I click on an `<option>` element inside `<select>`. The website changes the content of another `<select>` below it. This only happens when I manually select an option.

But when I select an option using Javascript like this: No content gets changed:

`document.getElementById("Category").selectedIndex = 8;`

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] here? (and maybe a link to the website in the meantime?)

Comment: Okay. I will do that, please wait few minutes, making changes

Comment: I doubt I can post reproducable code, since it's not my website. But the original website is this. https://www.vfsglobalservices-germany.com/

You first need to make an account, login, then click on schedule appointment. Then select anything from 4th list inside the form.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, I don't think people are going to sign up on some external website just to have a chance to see the behavior you're describing. There are many ways to achieve this sort of thing, but the code should be in the question for it to be debuggable

Comment: I think it should not matter. Basically, I want to replicate all the functions that can trigger when a human manually clicks on a select option, using javascript. Is it hard?

Comment: Just paste the whole code in your question. There is a high chance that there is something else wrong with your code and not the selectedIndex way of doing it

Comment: Or just make a JavaScript human-like click.

Comment: It's just one line code. I am using Chrome console

Comment: Let me paste the whole website's code? maybE?

Comment: If you want xD. No just check if the id on the select is correct. Otherwise idk, it should work

Comment: Can't paste whole code, work limit. Let me try to find the iD

Comment: Going to that site shows me `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.` Guess I"m not allowed there

Comment: Try this link https://www.vfsglobalservices-germany.com/Global-Appointment/Account/RegisteredLogin?q=shSA0YnE4pLF9Xzwon/x/OTV4izEu62H0fY/rwV/Z/qJNn6dti6LKGDbd4svtBYqkdyrRwvY4mPbaJnSq5k0wiCmcp5t2/PVG1ElNDMY/kEQ6yYpvmjL3wHerjsOxJ1dF3fbKws9yoJyEo4GoafNzg==

Comment: Any way to monitor which function gets executed in a browser on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let options= document.querySelectorAll('select option')
```

You can access the innerHTML property of first option using `options[0].innerHTML`

Add onChange event to you select element using

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',()=>{
alert('Changed')
})
```

Hope it helps

Edit - You might also want to check the current selected option and want to make changes accordingly. You can check the current selected option by

```
document.querySelector('select').value //Returns the value of selected option
```

Comment: Any way to monitor which function gets executed in a browser on click?

Comment: @johndoe can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Disclaimer: There is no reproducible example, so this is my best guess.</sup>

The website you are talking about probably captures the click events and uses that to alter the selects. For example,

```
$("select > option").click(function(){
   //do something
   ...
});
```

When you change the `selectedIndex`, yes, you are selecting a new option, but you are not sending the click event, so the above function is not called. You will need to inspect their source/provide more details for more clarity.

Comment: Any way to monitor which function gets executed in a browser on click?